# SQL Server 2022 graph database pseudo column in triggers

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases, sql-server-2022

I have a SQL Server 2022 database where I am defining the following trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER After_Assignment_Delete
ON dbo.[Assigned_To]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.[UpdateManifest]([DatabaseId], [UserId])
        SELECT db.[Id], u.[Id]
        FROM deleted a
        INNER JOIN [User] u ON a.$from_id = u.$node_id
        OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GetAssignedDatabases](u.[Id]) db
END
```

This trigger will build and work as I expect, however, if I change the trigger to an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger I get the error

> Invalid column name '$from_id'

Are `INSTEAD OF` triggers on edge tables not supported?

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER After_Assignment_Delete
ON dbo.[Assigned_To]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.[UpdateManifest]([DatabaseId], [UserId])
        SELECT db.[Id], u.[Id]
        FROM deleted a
        INNER JOIN [User] u ON a.$from_id = u.$node_id
        OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GetAssignedDatabases](u.[Id]) db
END
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, but shouldn't you join between deleted and the main table and use the main table's pseudo-columns

Comment: $node_id also does not exist on deleted for instead of triggers. This is a really good idea if you have another identifier on your edge table.

Comment: I am going to change my edge tables to have a PK (I was relying on $node_id). This will let be join back to the main table and us the pseudo columns as @siggemannen suggested. Thanks!

Comment: This strategy doesn't work with INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers since you don't have any information on the edge relationship at all in the trigger without  pseudo columns.

Comment: Why do you want to use instead of at all? i've written a lot of triggers in my life, but never had any need for it

Comment: My TVF recursively (transitive closure) gets it results. The delete will effect that result so I need to get the initial assignments before the delete in order to get the delta, i.e. the record being deleted has tangential effects on the results of the TVF. I don't need a trigger. This could be done in the stored procedure that does the delete. A trigger seems to be more appropriate to ensure the delta gets logged if records are deleted outside of the stored procedure.

This is the first time I have ever had need of an INSTEAD OF trigger myself.